# Error: ANCHOR_PROVIDER_URL is not defined

Tags: anchor

When i am running my tests in an anchor workspace and i am getting this error.[image]

Comment: please replace this screenshot with the text in a code block so the indexer can improve discoverability of this question

Comment: I better add it but i don't get this error anymore for indexing i have put the same message in the title so its discoverable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR**

Try creating a `.env` and set `ANCHOR_PROVIDER_URL` as `http://localhost:8899` in case of localnet, or use the devnet/mainnet RPC-API endpoints if you're not using the local cluster.

**Possible explanation**

Assuming that you are using the default anchor configuration for testing your scripts, which is set in `Anchor.toml` as,

```
test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts"
```

this might be because anchor is unable to parse the environment variables which it reads from `Anchor.toml` during this function call in the test file.

[image: Calling from test file]

You can see the call's source code here.

[image: Reading of environment variables]

Comment: please replace screenshots with text in code blocks so the indexer can improve discoverability of this post